# Alguien sabe como llamar una función desde HTML a JS

Tags: html, nodejs

> Tengo una situación que no puedo hacer funcionar

```
<body>  
  <a href="javascript:buttonBarcode('864126673800090001785002019700232050202099')">link text</a> //A  
  <script type="text/javascript"> buttonBarcode('1'); </script> //B
  <br><br>  
  <div id="result"></div> 
</body>
```

> La opción A funciona cuando hago clic, la opcion B me da
> error:buttonBarcode is not defined. SI alguien me ayuda por favor, no puedo encontrarle la vuelta
>
> Agrego la funcion en JS
> barcode_sample.js

```
function buttonBarcode(v) {
    var bars, intHt, intWd, strImages;
      'use strict';
        intHt = intWd = 0;
        strImages = "";
    
        intWd = 4; 
        intHt = 45; 
        strText = '864126673800090001785002019700232050202099';
        funcCode128B();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = strImages = genBarcode(strRaw, intWd, intHt); 
    };
```

Comment: `buttonBarcode` es una función que definiste tu? Si no es el caso, seguro que dicha función esta implementada en JS?

Comment: SI es una función hecha por mi y esta en JS

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por que haciendo click funciona y llamándola directamente no función, necesito que la segunda opción funcione.

Comment: Deberías especificar en que parte del html realizas la carga de barcode_sample.js del posicionamiento y modo de carga (si fuera asíncrona o no) depende si la función ya se cargo o no

Comment: Efrain gracias por escribir, ya encontré la solución. Todo pasaba por la parte de asíncronica, la buscaba tarde creo, un setTimeout me mostró el camino por así decirlo.